# Conditional text height based on paper size

Tags: margins

How to make the text height in a document change dynamically based on the selected paper size (letter or A4).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    \setlength{\textheight}{9.2in} % change this value based on a4paper option

\begin{document}
     text....
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe geometry and KOMA do this sort of thing automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for a `\pdfmatch` of `a4paper` within the document class options. If a match is found, `\pdfmatch` returns 1:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
% Check if a4paper options was passed in class option list
\ifnum\pdfmatch{a4paper}{\@classoptionslist}=1
  \setlength{\textheight}{9.2in}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text....
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could test for the page size using

```
\ifdim\paperheight=297mm \textheight=9.21in\fi% note the space
```

where (from article.cls)

```
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {210mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {148mm}}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {250mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {176mm}}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {14in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {10.5in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {7.25in}}
\DeclareOption{landscape}
   {\setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
    \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}}
```

Comment: might as well do something like: `\setlength{\textheight}{0.8\paperheight}` which would be a relative setting of textheight.